# 80386 real mode simulator

Tags: debugging, assembly

I am looking for 80386 real mode simulator, can you recommend some? I am interested just in CPU core and memory, I dont need peripherals and accurate modeling of instruction execution time due to pipelining. I have already briefly tried simulator included in dosbox but didnt liked its UI much. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What specifically are you looking for? Any x86 simulator will load the bootloader in real mode. [qemu](http://www.qemu.org) and [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) are both free and can emulate x86 processors.

Comment: And bochs even has built-in debugger. qemu is supposedly able to connect to gdb, but I never got that working in 16 bit mode.

Comment: @Jester The -s flag enables the debugger port, and the -S (capital s) tells it to wait for the debugger before starting. Maybe you were past real mode when you connected?

Comment: Actually I think it connected, just that gdb wasn't very happy with 16 bit real mode (my gdb being 64 bit, even).

Comment: @Jester Yeah, you are probably right then. gdb doesn't notice its in real mode so it disassembles as if it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

There is also dosbox, also with its own debugger.